# awk to update portion of a line in file1 matching another filed in file2

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to update only the lines in `file2` that start with `>`, where `$2` in `file1` matches after the second `_`. If it does that portion in updated with `$1` of `file1`. I am also trying to remove after the update the last `_` in the field, but I am not sure how. The `awk` executes but currently I get all of `file1` and `file2` printed.  If I just print, I can see that only the `>` lines are being searched, but I am not sure. There may not always be a match and nothing needs to happen or get processed. Thank you :).

file1  `space delimited`

```
SCN1A NM_001165963.1
SCN1B NM_001037.4
```

**file2**  `space delimited`

```
 >hg19_ncbiRefSeq_NM_001165963.1_2 range=chr2:166912896-166913035 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
 ....
 ....
 >hg19_ncbiRefSeq_NM_001165963.1_4 range=chr2:166909337-166909478 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
 ....
 ....
```

**desired output**

```
>hg19_ncbiRefSeq_SCN1A range=chr2:166912896-166913035 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
....
....
>hg19_ncbiRefSeq_SCN1A range=chr2:166909337-166909478 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
....
....
```

**awk**

```
awk '/^>/; {a[$2]=$1; next} a[$1]{$1=a[$1]}1' file1 file2
```

commented `awk`

```
awk '
FNR==NR{  # process same line
 a[$2]=$1  # use $2 to and store $1 in a
   next    # process next line
}
  />/{  # each line starting with >
   for(i in a){  # start loop
   value=""
    if(match($0,i)){   # look for match in i 
    value=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  # store match in value
      sub(/^_[0-9]+ /,"",value)   # update the NM_digits only
     print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[i],value  # print the updated i with portion below
      next  # process next line
    }
  }
}
 1   # update output
 '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$2]=$1
   next
}
/>/{
   for(i in a){
     value=""
     if(match($0,i)){
       value=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
       sub(/^_[0-9]+ /,"",value)
       print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[i],value
       next
     }
   }
}
1
' Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Output for sample Input shown will be as follows.

```
 >hg19_ncbiRefSeq_SCN1A range=chr2:166912896-166913035 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
 ....
 ....
 >hg19_ncbiRefSeq_SCN1A range=chr2:166909337-166909478 5'pad=25 3'pad=25
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much :), can I post back with comments in a little bit. Thank you :).

Comment: @cm0728, sure let me know if this helps you.

Comment: The `awk` works great thank you.  I posted my comments in the post :).